Superbase similarity checker
I am trying to check for the already existing data in Superbas table the similarity with the input data, and it constantly gives me some problems in terminal console, so what can I do to Mae changes in such way so I can constantly add new info to table and compare it through the embeddings technologies, so can you help me have to figure out this error?:
code:
    embedding = await create_embedding(input_text)
    match = await find_nearest_match(embedding)
    if match:
        await get_chat_completion(match, input_text)
    else:
        print("No matching document found.")

# Create an embedding vector representing the input text
async def create_embedding(input_text):
    response = client.embeddings.create(
        model="text-embedding-3-small",
        input=input_text
    )
    return response.data[0].embedding

# Query Supabase and return a semantically matching text chunk
async def find_nearest_match(embedding):
    response = supabase.rpc('documents', {
        'query_embedding': embedding,
        'match_threshold': 0,
        'match_count': 1
    }).execute()
    if response.data and len(response.data) > 0:
        return response.data[0]['content']
    else:
        return None

# Use OpenAI to make the response conversational
async def get_chat_completion(text, query):
    chat_messages = [{
        'role': 'system',
        'content': (
            "You are an enthusiastic podcast expert who loves recommending podcasts to people. "
            "You will be given two pieces of information - some context about podcasts episodes "
            "and a question. Your main job is to formulate a short answer to the question using the provided context. "
            "If you are unsure and cannot find the answer in the context, say, 'Sorry, I don't know the answer.' "
            "Please do not make up the answer."
        )
    }, {
        'role': 'user',
        'content': f"Context: {text} Question: {query}"
    }]


    response = client.chat.completions.create(
        model='gpt-4o',
        messages=chat_messages,
        temperature=0.5,
        frequency_penalty=0.5
    )

    print(response['choices'][0]['message']['content'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main(query))```




error:
 ```postgrest.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 'PGRST202', 'details': 'Searched for the function public.documents with parameters match_count, match_threshold, query_embedding or with a single unnamed json/jsonb parameter, but no matches were found in the schema cache.', 'hint': 'Perhaps you meant to call the function public.match_documents', 'message': 'Could not find the function public.documents(match_count, match_threshold, query_embedding) in the schema cache'}```

